# Draw horizontal lines on points shapefile using ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, point, line

I have one shapefile of 200 points in which I would like to draw one horizontal line of 2Km on each of those points.

[image: Shapefile]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some python code which you can execute in the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm):

```
import arcpy, os

shapefile_folder = r'C:\folder'#Change to match your data
point_shapefile = 'points.shp' #Change to match your data

hlines = 'Horizontal_lines.shp'
lenght_of_lines = 1000 #on each side of the point

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=shapefile_folder, out_name=hlines, 
                                   geometry_type='POLYLINE', 
                                   spatial_reference=arcpy.Describe(point_shapefile).spatialReference)
icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(hlines,'SHAPE@')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(shapefile_folder,point_shapefile),['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        poly=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(row[0]-lenght_of_lines,row[1]),arcpy.Point(row[0]+lenght_of_lines,row[1])]))
        icur.insertRow([poly])
del icur
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Bera, Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried your code but I got one error: 

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
>>> 

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: Yes I did, I have changed the 'C:\database.gdb' to the path of my .gdb file, and I have change the name 'points' to the name of my point shapefile..

Comment: This is so odd... No I have not removed the r... I used exactly this code:

import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\testes\trechos4.gdb' #Change to match your data
points = 'vertices_testes' #Change to match your data

The rest of the code I did not change one thing

Comment: Dear BERA, Sorry for the late reply I was just jumping of happiness! :D IT WORKED!! You sir, don't know how much you have helped me on this! Thank you so, so, so much!!!

Comment: Of course I can! I have already done that!! Thanks again, I'm really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Dear @BERA, can I ask you one more question? Imagine that instead of an horizontal line I would like to have one line but with 2º angle. The changes to the code are massive?

Thanks

Comment: You only need to change what is in the two arcpy.Point on the line starting with poly=

Comment: I need to change this line, correct? poly=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(row[0]-lenght_of_lines,row[1]),arcpy.Point(row[0]+lenght_of_lines,row[1])]))
        icur.insertRow([poly])

Can you tell me to what should I have to change if I wanted a 2ºangle line? 

Thanks

Comment: You need to calculate the coordinates of the left and right line ends using trigonometry. Row[0] is x of the center point, row[1] is y. Ask a new question and include thr code.

Comment: Dear @BERA I have created one new question. I have tried to change on my own but I couldn't... Thank you