# Modifying python code to draw line with 2º angle?

Tags: arcpy

In [Draw horizontal lines on points shapefile using ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/262047/115) , @BERA , made this following code for me:

```
import arcpy, os
shapefile_folder = r'C:\folder'#Change to match your data
point_shapefile = 'points.shp' #Change to match your data

hlines = 'Horizontal_lines.shp'
lenght_of_lines = 1000 #on each side of the point

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=shapefile_folder, out_name=hlines, 
                                   geometry_type='POLYLINE', 
                                   spatial_reference=arcpy.Describe(point_shapefile).spatialReference)
icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(hlines,'SHAPE@')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(shapefile_folder,point_shapefile),['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        poly=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(row[0]-lenght_of_lines,row[1]),arcpy.Point(row[0]+lenght_of_lines,row[1])]))
        icur.insertRow([poly])
del icur
```

What this code does is it draws one horizontal line on a shapefile of points.

Instead of a horizontal line I would like to have one line but with 2º angle.

Can someone tell me the changes to this code?

Comment: Which way do you want the 2 degrees to go? from the start or from the end? It's simple Pythagorean calculation using the math lib https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html , start by importing math and then use cos and sin to work out the X and Y difference from the fixed point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import arcpy, os
shapefile_folder = r'C:\folder'#Change to match your data
point_shapefile = 'points.shp' #Change to match your data

hlines = 'Horizontal_lines.shp'
length_of_lines_X = 1000 #on each side of the point
length_of_lines_Y = 34.920769491747730500402625773725

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=shapefile_folder, out_name=hlines, geometry_type='POLYLINE', 

spatial_reference=arcpy.Describe(point_shapefile).spatialReference)
icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(hlines,'SHAPE@')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(shapefile_folder,point_shapefile),['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        poly=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(row[0]-length_of_lines_X,row[1]-length_of_lines_Y),arcpy.Point(row[0]+length_of_lines_X,row[1]+length_of_lines_Y)]))
        icur.insertRow([poly])
del icur
```

A simple case of Pythagoras? Give it a go and see if you get the result you are after. Maybe check my math first ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you create the start and end points of the line, you'll need to do some simple trigonometry to figure out what the x and y of each point will be. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222062830/http://mathforum.org/sarah/hamilton/ham.1side.1angle.html) is a useful page.  Use the NAK chart because you know one side (the 1000 unit) hypotenuse, and one angle, 2 deg. Looking at the diagram below the chart, you'll want to find the "adjacent" and "opposite" sides of the triangle.

The "adjacent" side would be your x offset (from the origin's x):

```
xOffset = cos(theta) x hypotenuse
```

The "opposite" side is your y offset (from the origin's y):

```
yOffset = sin(theta) x hypotenuse
```

It's been a long time since I've done any trigonometry problems, so there may be some errors in the details, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That is correct, but could you put it into a snippet of the users' code, or python in the least, to show how to implement it thus improving your already correct answer to +1 worthy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MichaelStimson. I suppose I hesitated to a give a full code solution because I wanted the user to know "why" to make those changes- not just the changes to make. You can see in the previous linked post, the user showed no level of effort in research or code writing to begin with. You're correct that the other answer is more thorough and includes actual code. As that answer has already done so, I will leave my answer as is.